# One accordion open at a time

Tags: jquery

Creating a collapsible menu, but need one accordion to be open at a time, if I click one another link then first should collapse.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav left-navbar" id="sidenav01">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed">
                                    Submenu 1
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo2" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed">
                                Submenu 2
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo2">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu2.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu2.2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Submenu2.3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/7fwv1eud/1/)**

Comment: You should try [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example).

Comment: Hi Shubham, I can't change the above code, I am going to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below work around to collapse other opened div with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navbar-nav li a').on('click', function () {
    console.log('cilcked 2');
    $('.navbar-nav li a').not(this).next('div').removeClass('show');
});
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5tp7z6h/2/)

Comment: happy to help you. you can upvote and accept this answer if find it useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show default open collapsed menu just add 'show' class.
and use jquery below

```
$('.collapsed').click(function(){
    $(this).next().addClass('show');
    $('.collapse').removeClass('show');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeshmule/2qcatm4L/1/)